# Как запросить список чисел в одну строку?

Tags: python

знаю только такой способ, но далее в задании к нему не применить метод `len(s)`

```
s = map(int, input())
```

как можно по другому создать список из введенных чисел в одну строку через пробел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так вы `map` в список превратите и можете применять `len`

```
s = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

или

```
s = [*map(int, input().split())]
```

и кстати вы забыли разбить ввод через `split()`, без этого этот метод не работает

Comment: Без split() оно даст список цифр введенного числа.